# INSERT not working, using SQL PLUS in ORACLE, simple table with type defined, perfectly created but not inserting values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
DROP TYPE Position;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE 
Position AS OBJECT
(longitude NUMBER(11,7),
lattitude NUMBER(11,7),
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Position(
    long NUMBER,
    latt NUMBER
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)FINAL;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Position AS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Position(
    long NUMBER,
    latt NUMBER
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
  BEGIN
      SELF.longitude := long;
      SELF.lattitude := latt;
  RETURN;
  END;

END;
/

DESC Position;


DROP TABLE District_Info;

CREATE TABLE District_Info(
Dname VARCHAR2(20),
DPos Position,
Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20),
Launch_ghat CHAR(1)
);

DESC District_Info;


INSERT INTO District_Info (Dname,DPos,Boundary_dist,Launch_ghat)
VALUES ('d',Position(1.1, 1.1),'gr','y');
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add an actual question, and explain what "not working" means. Are yo getting an error message? If so, what *exactly* does it say?

Comment: Have you committed the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have defined two constructors of the same type, but you didn't realize you did probably.

When you create an object type, Oracle creates a default constructor, with parameters that match the parameters of the type. Therefore, when you also defined a constructor with only lattitude and longitude as inputs, Oracle cannot work out which constructor to call, the default created one, or your one, so it errors with:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06553: PLS-307: too many declarations of 'POSITION' match this call
```

To fix this, you can simplify your code:

```
drop type position;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Position AS OBJECT (longitude NUMBER(11,7), lattitude NUMBER(11,7))
/

DROP TABLE District_Info;

CREATE TABLE District_Info( Dname VARCHAR2(20), DPos Position, Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20), Launch_ghat CHAR(1) );


INSERT INTO District_Info (Dname,DPos,Boundary_dist,Launch_ghat) VALUES ('d',Position(1.1),'gr','y');
```

Ie, you don't need the constructor declaration or the body. If you like, you can have a DIFFERENT constructor, eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Position AS OBJECT (longitude NUMBER(11,7), lattitude NUMBER(11,7),
-- Define a constructor that has only 2 parameters.
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION position(i_longitude NUMBER)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Position AS 
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION position(i_longitude NUMBER)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS 
  BEGIN 
    SELF.longitude := i_longitude; 
    SELF.lattitude := i_longitude; 
    RETURN; -- self; 
  END;
END; 
/

show errors;

DROP TABLE District_Info;

CREATE TABLE District_Info( Dname VARCHAR2(20), DPos Position, Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20), Launch_ghat CHAR(1) );

DESC District_Info;

INSERT INTO District_Info (Dname,DPos,Boundary_dist,Launch_ghat) VALUES ('d',Position(1.1),'gr','y');
```